# stop this error ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failu

Tags: php

i keep receiving this error in my error log file :

`ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failu...`

i tried to catch it but no luck, it still appears there as well as another error :

`socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer` for another module.

i am aware of these errors, and i want my code to do something whenever an error happens, the 2 functions return values and tells that there is an error, but still i can't stop the php-error from getting written in my log !

any ideas help ?

Comment: Do you want to stop the error, or stop the logging of the error?

Comment: stop logging the error

Comment: follow example 1 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) to make all non fatal errors into catchable exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress all error messages that one expression may generate, use the [`@` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) like this:

```
$ftp = @ftp_connect('ftp.example.com');
```

To be used with care, obviously.

Comment: isn't there any other method than this one ? it's too expensive to display errors false then true ...

Comment: @RonanDejhero What do you mean by "expensive" and by "display errors false then true"? This operator suppresses errors for the one single expression it precedes.

Comment: and actually tried that before on `socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [104]` it doesn't work

Comment: ,the error suppression with `@` usually works like the ini_set('display_errors'), it sets the global value to true, then false after that line is executed, i don't know whow php5.3 works now, but that was the deal with older versions of php and that is big deal on servers with huge traffic

Comment: The `@` can be used in front of any arbitrary expression (please check its manual page) and suppresses errors for this expression **only**. That is does not work for this particular case is another story.

Comment: i will use it as a temporary solution though i didn't want to . thanks man

Comment: An alternative solution is to write a custom exception handler. The example pointed out by Orangepill is much more elegant a solution.

Comment: oh didn't notice that one !